# Meaning of "a type/class/function/module/... object"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I read Python in a Nutshell, I saw a "type object", "class object", "function object", "module object", ....

Does a "xxx object" mean an instance of type "xxx"?

For example,

- does a type object mean an instance of type `type`? For example, is `int` a type object? is a specific class a type object?
- does a class object mean an instance of what? Is a specific class a class object? For example,

  > A class is a Python object with several characteristics:
  >
  > • You  can  call  a  **class  object**  as  if  it  were  a  function.
  >   The  call,  often  known  as instantiation, returns an object known as
  >   an instance of the class; the class is known as the type of the
  >   instance.
  >
  > • A  class  can  inherit  from  other  classes,  meaning  it 
  >   delegates  to  other  **class objects** the lookup of attributes that
  >   are not found in the class itself.
- does a function object mean an instance of `types.FunctionType`? Is a specific function a function object?
- does a module object mean an instance of `types.ModuleType`? Is a specific module a module object?
- is there an int object? If yes, does it mean an integer value (e.g. `12`) of type `int`?

Thanks.

Comment: Two articles that are helpful: [Python MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) and [Alex Martelli's Object Model](http://www.aleax.it/Python/nylug05_om.pdf)

Comment: @dawg Thanks. Is Python's object/data model almost the same as any other object oriented language, such as C#, Java, C++, Ruby, Smalltalk, ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does a type object mean an instance of type `type`? For example, is `int` a type object? Ιs a specific class a type object?

Yes, a "type" object means an object of type "type", ergo an instance of that type. Information on what type something is can always be checked with `isinstance`. To answer your second question, is `int` an object of type `type`:

```
>>> isinstance(int, type) # True
```

Are custom classes type objects:

```
>>> class Spammy: 
...     pass
>>> isinstance(Spammy, type)
True
```

> Does a class object mean an instance of what? Is a specific class a class object?

The use of class object is interchangeable with the term `type` object after the [Unification of types and classes](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/) in Python 2.2. The term 'classes' is mainly used to refer to user defined classes (the ones you create with the `class` statement) but it really means the same thing.

This *did* make a difference in Python 2 that has old style classes. Not inheriting from object in a class definition gave an object of type `classobj`:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
>>> type(Foo)
<type 'classobj'>
```

This just doesn't exist in Python 3 where all classes are objects of type `type`.

> Does a function object mean an instance of `types.FunctionType`? Is a specific function a function object?
>
> Does a module object mean an instance of `types.ModuleType`? Is a specific module a module object?

Yes to all of these:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
>>> type(foo)  
function 
>>> import collections    
>>> type(collections)
module
```

> Is there an `int` object? If yes, does it mean an integer value (e.g. `12`) of type `int`?

There is an `int` type, which is a type object and an `int` object, which is an object of type `int`. An example of that is `12` since:

```
>>> type(12)
int
```

While, the same thing on `int` yields:

```
>>> type(int)
type
```

Comment: And `isinstance(False, int)` is `True` since `<type 'bool'>` is a subclass of `int`

Comment: Thanks. (1) "You don't usually say a 'class' object. " I added some examples to the post, so it might be helpful to guess what a class object mean. (2) "you can always use isinstance to check that." I don't know how to use `isinstance` to find out what a class object is.

Comment: @Tim I've updated my answer to include that part. In short, class object is the same thing as type object. In the past this wasn't always the case but in Python 3 it is.

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation of [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#type):

> With one argument, return the type of an object. The return value is a type object and generally the same object as returned by `object.__class__`.
>
> The `isinstance()` built-in function is recommended for testing the type of an object, because it takes subclasses into account.

Let's see. Is `int` a type object?

```
>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>
```

A class object means an instance of what? In Python 3, classes are always [new-style classes](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) so they constitute a `type` of themselves:

```
>>> class X:
...     pass
... 
>>> y = X()
>>> type(y)
<class '__main__.X'>
```

But with Python 2.x's old-style classes:

```
>>> class X:
...     pass
... 
>>> y = X()
>>> type(y)
<type 'instance'>
>>> type(X)
<type 'classobj'>
```

Here, the class has `types.ClassType` and the instance has `types.InstanceType` (neither of which exists in Python 3.x)

A function object is a `types.FunctionType`:

```
>>> def foo():
...    return 42
>>> type(foo) is types.FunctionType
True
>>> type(lambda x: x + 2) is types.FunctionType
True
```

A module object is a `types.ModuleType`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> type(sys) is types.ModuleType
True
```

And yes, there are `int` objects. Consider `type(12)`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can represent types as objects themselves.  So yes, they're type objects.  For every type there is an object representing that type, like `int`.  It's an instance of the *type* itself.

It's like `.getClass()` and `Class<?>` objects in Java: `"some string".getClass() == String.class`.  Java doesn't treat functions as first class values so there's types like `Callable`, `Consumer<T>`, etc., but in Python there's a specific type for functions, and with that a specific object representing that type.